# How do I specify default subcommand?

Tags: kotlin, picocli

Is there a way to print help message when user didn't provide subcommand ?

Following doesn't work because it runs callable that doesn't have implementation.

```kotlin
@Command(
        name = "tool",
        mixinStandardHelpOptions = true,
        subcommands = [ListPlugins::class, RunJob::class, CommandLine.HelpCommand::class])
class Main : Callable<Int> {

    override fun call(): Int {
//        CommandLine.HelpCommand().run()
        return 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rephrase the question: How to show help when the user didn’t specify a subcommand?

From picoli version 4.3, you can simply *not* implement `Callable` on the top-level command; this makes it mandatory for users to specify a subcommand. (This assumes that you use [`CommandLine.execute`](https://picocli.info/#execute) to parse the command line and run the business logic.)

If no subcommand is specified, a "Missing required subcommand" error message is displayed, followed by the usage help message.

See: https://picocli.info/#_required_subcommands for details.

Does that meet your requirements?

Comment: Thank you for prompt response, Remko!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example, you can make a fake call without command line parameters. (instead of args-> --help)
And after it with the parameters, according to the instructions.
For example, the code in Java:

```
CommandLine helpCL = new CommandLine(new Main());
helpCL.execute(new String[]{"--help"});
return new CommandLine(new Main()).execute(args);
```